# Reverse Proxy in Python using WSGI

Tags: python, proxy, wsgi, reverse-proxy

app, built with Flask.
I want to have the following routing :

```
"/"     -> my Flask app
"/foo/" -> Reverse proxy toward http://bar/
```

So far, I don't have any reverse proxy, so my application looks like :

```
import app
[...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.app.secret_key = 'XXX'
    app.app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I would like to have the whole project only in python. I don't want any Apache or nginx stack (the project is not meant to be on public network). I saw that I could use a Python WSGI server, such as "wsgiserver" in cherrypy, so my app would be:

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
import app

d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({
    '/': app.app.wsgi_app
})
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      server.start()
```

And if I want to add a reverse proxy in "/foo", I guess I'll just need to :

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
import app

d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({
    '/': app.app.wsgi_app,
    '/foo/': SOME_WSGI_REVERSE_PROXY
})
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      server.start()
```

So my questions are :

- Is there any reverse proxy, written in python, that are WSGI compliant ? (I don't know if any `SOME_WSGI_REVERSE_PROXY` exists)
- Would it work with this kind of implementation ?

Comment: Please don't edit questions to include answers in them. That's what the answer section is for. You can post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an actively maintained alternative to the original wsgiproxy now:
https://pypi.org/project/WSGIProxy2/